# c++ how to split space separated wstring keeping the values inside quotes?

Tags: c++, string, tokenize, string-parsing, wstring

I am reading a registry key in wstring. The value i get in wstring looks like below :

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\folder\binary.exe" "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\folder\folder_cfg.json" "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\folder\log\log.log" install

I want the second path in the wstring string above. I have tried other approaches, but they are detecting the space separated string by using escape character "\" . However the string I get from registry does not have it.How to get this done without having escape character (And not allowed to use boost::tokenizer)?

Comment: Have you tried regex?

Comment: no, can we get it done without regex ? @nick

Comment: I'd `find` the `" "`, advance one character and then `substr` twice, one from the beginning to the found position and the other from the found position to the end.

Comment: You might have quotes within quotes, so things get really tricky then, though a well-constructed regular expression can handle this.

Comment: @tadman  , These are just location paths , why would they have qoutes within qoutes.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes a path can include characters that force the use of quotes to properly represent it. In fact the quotes already in use in the example may be the result of the spaces within the path. This means I need to amend my suggestion above to `find` the first space or `find` the first space in quotes if there are multiple spaces.

Comment: Ah, on Windows `"` is not allowed in a filename, but on other platforms it is.

Comment: @user4581301 could you please help with by listing sample code ?

Comment: [Documentation on the `find` method.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)